# Sum Comparison from another MySQL Table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables listed below.  Column 3 of table 2 is the FK to column 1 of table 1. Col_2 or table 1 shows how much stock I have bought total.  And table 2 column 2 shows how much of that stock has sold in one large chunk.  So the first two records of table 2 show that I have sold 250 and 200 of product one. This will leave me with 50 units of product 1.

My question is, how can I build a query that will pull only the products for which I still have stock for. In the example below, I would show only the products for which stock was greater than 0. If this sounds too complicated, I am open to suggestions on how this could be performed better.

```
Table 1
Col_1   Col_2
======  =====
1       500
2       500
3       400

Table 2
Col_1   Col_2   Col_3 (FK table1 Col_1)
======  ======  =======================
1       250     1
2       200     1
3       400     2
4       400     3

Desired result
Col_1(t1)   Col_2(remaining stock)
========    ======================
1           50
2           100
```

Comment: Read up on [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
SELECT Col_1, Col_2 - Sold as Remaining_Stock FROM Table_1 JOIN
(SELECT Col_3, SUM(Col_2) as Sold FROM Table_2 GROUP BY Col_3) as Table_Sold
ON Table_1.Col_1 = Table_Sold.Col_3 AND Col_2 > Sold
```

The subquery totals up your sales, then a simple join with your inventory should do it.

Comment: This works fine, took me a bit to get the right columns in the right place and think about it for a bit.d  Thank you.

Comment: Well I do have one more issue.  How can I also pull sums from table 1 that do not have a record in table 2?  Currently it only shows records that exist in both tables.  I tried a left join but it didn't work. Sorry, I am very new to mysql and have trouble visualizing this.

Comment: A left outer join with SUM(Col_2) as Inventory in select fields. You will need to remove the join criteria Col_2 > Sold as well.